# Mots composés : un seul mot, deux mots ou trait d'union

Tags: mots-composés

Trois noms composés : *portemanteau*, *timbre-poste*, *residence secondaire*.

Existe-t-il des règles générales (i.e. rules of thumb:-)!) qui définissent quand un mot composé est écrit en un seul mot et quand avec un trait d'union ? Par exemple, je vois tantôt porte-manteau, tantôt portemanteau.

Comment: Je ne sais pas s'il y a une règle générale, mais en tut cas: *résidence secondaire* n'est pas un mot composé: "secondaire" est simplement un adjectif qui qualifie "résidence".

Comment: Je crois qu'il y a pas mal de règles/exceptions dans ce cas précis, surtout avec les préconisations pour la réforme de la langue fr de 1990. voir notamment quelques éléments ici https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990, tableau "règles", n. 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non pas de règles générales.
Pour information, porte-manteau est different de portemanteau.
Voir [portemanteau](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/portemanteau/62761) et [porte-manteau](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porte-manteau_(office))

Answer (score 3):

Depuis mon passage lointain à l'école élémentaire, j'ai pensé qu'un mot composé était par définition avec un trait d'union.

C'est bien la présence de ce trait d'union qui fait que les mots gardent une part d'autonomie et par conséquent donnent des sueurs froides à tous les élèves qui lors de la dictée subissent les règles du pluriel des mots composés.

Lorsque deux mots sont collés sans trait d'union, le résultat est un mot unique et le pluriel ne peut être marqué qu'à la fin.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que la [Banque](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=Mots%20compos%C3%A9s%20&btn_chercher=CHERCHER) de dépannage linguistique parle du sujet de façon exhaustive. il existe est cette publication de 47 (!) pages du Laboratoire de Linguistique Informatique de l'Université Paris Nord, CNRS (UMR 0195)) : https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00433841/document.